# complete a pic with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to complete this pic

code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}
\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=2mm]}-{|[width=2mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]
\coordinate (a) at (1,1);
\coordinate (b) at (3,3);


\coordinate (c) at (0,0);
\coordinate (d) at (4,4);


\draw[ultra thick,black, ->]  (b) -- node[above left] {\Large $\vec{v}$} (a);

\draw[thick,black, dashed]  (c) -- node[above left] {} (d);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

like this:

[image]

Can you help me to complete this pic? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Something similar to your sketch (which is not a `pic` but picture ...):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,arrows.meta,calc,quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth,
every pin/.style  = {inner sep=1pt, align=left, 
                     pin edge={<-, solid, black, shorten <=0.5mm}},
                    ]
\coordinate[pin=below right:some text ?] (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,4);
%
\coordinate (c) at (1,1);
\coordinate (d) at (3,3);
%
\draw[thick, dashed]    (a) -- node[above left] {} (b);
\draw[ultra thick, ->]  (d) -- (c) 
        node[pos=0.95,
             circle, draw=red, thin, minimum size=2em,
             pin={[text=red]right:some longer red\\ text in two lines ?}] {};
%
\draw[{Bar[].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[]}]    
    ($(d)!7mm!-90:(c)$) -- node[above, sloped] {some text} 
    ($(c)!7mm!+90:(d)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]